# Make a poster!

Tags: discussion

I'm planning of putting up some A4 chem.SE posters in my institute, and I though that it would be useful if I had some for Physics as well (more useful, in fact, since I'm in the Physics  department)

The poster I'm using is this one (click to enlarge):

[image]

taken from https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/how-do-we-promote-our-shiny-new-site.Use it for inspiration if you need any :)

Does anyone feel up to making a similar poster for Physics.

Stuff to keep in mind:

- Don't forget a QR code! There are some easy QR generators online, just Google it.
- I don't know if we are allowed to put the Phy.SE logo onto posters, etc--it's copyright, though this may count as fair use. You may have to ask on the mother meta, or just use a different image.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/what-are-the-rules-on-using-the-stack-overflow-logo